# Why can't I export a curve to Collada?

Tags: export, bezier-curves, collada, three.js

I want to export a Bezier curve object to Collada (to load with `Three.js`). **When I export my scene, the curve won't show in the Collada file, unless I convert it to a mesh first.**

Comment: i don't think collada supports cuves.

Comment: Does .OBJ support them?

Comment: try STL. i think i've seen it work in there before